# Is folder name shadowing 3rd-party package name or Python module name is an anti-pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, architecture, anti-patterns

Consider the following (very simplified) project structure:

```
project/
    src/
        collections/
        validators/
        foo/
        bar/
```

The "collections" sub-directory name shadows the Python's "collections" module.

The "validators" sub-directory name shadows "validators" 3rd-party package name.

### Question:

**Is it an anti-pattern to have sub-directories with the same names as Python modules or 3rd-party packages?**

Note, the real project structure has about 100 sub-directories, so it is a bit hard to do not shadow names.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, shadowing is discouraged.
The problem is : tomorrow you install a new dependency, which tries to import `collections` and end up importing something else than what it expected.

The usual practice is to put all your code in a module named after your poject, like so :

```
project/
    src/
        myapp/
            collections/
            validators/
            foo/
            bar/
```

That way, your imports will be `import myapp.collections`, which is both clear to delimitate external from internal dependencies (as recommended by the [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)) and it will prevent any collision with other library.

(you may have to adjust a little the way you start your application to have your PYTHONPATH pointing to `src/myapp`)