# What to do when U have a circular import

Tags: python, random, import

I'm having an attribute error on my random module

I tried using random module to identify the 'randint' of a particular range of numbers but pycharm is saying that the module 'random' Has no attribute 'randint'. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you have tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot any issues you might have with that. Also please post the errors you are getting when running the code.

Comment: It sounds like you've named a file `random.py`. So, not a circular import.

Comment: check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70731827/is-folder-name-shadowing-3rd-party-package-name-or-python-module-name-is-an-anti